# Parsing the string "009" as integer in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

how to parse **009** in javascript i need return value as **9** but it returns 0.
But when i parse **001 it returns 1**.

```
var tenant_id_max = '3-009';
tenant_id_split = tenant_id_max.split("-");
var tenant_id_int = tenant_id_split[1];
var tenant_id_count = parseInt(tenant_id_int);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do

```
var tenant_id_count = parseInt(tenant_id_int, 10);
```

That's because a string starting with "0" is parsed as octal (which doesn't work very well for "009", hence the 0 you get) if you don't specify the radix.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) :

> If the input string begins with "0", radix is eight (octal). This
>   feature is non-standard, and some implementations deliberately do not
>   support it (instead using the radix 10). For this reason always
>   specify a radix when using parseInt.

The most important thing to remember is **Always specify the radix**.

Comment: It means parse it as a bes 10 (decimal) number.  Number strings starting with a 0 get parsed automatically as base 8